# Json.NET error handling fails when serializing to specific object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to use `JsonSerializerSettings` for custom error handling, but when I specify the object type the error stops in runtime debugging. The "json" is no valid JSON, due to remote error that is out of my hands to change/fix.

Working:

```
var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
    Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
      // My error handling
    }
});
```

Breaks With:

> Additional information: Error converting value "Received merchantid does not match a registered merchant" to type 'TransmitModels+errorData'. Path ...

```
TransmitModels.errorData responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransmitModels.errorData>(json,new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
    Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
      // My error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: You json doesn't match to `TransmitModels.errorData`

Comment: @EZI I would like to handle that event gracefully.

Comment: provide a sample `json`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh As mentioned in the question the response is not valid Json, It´s just a sting e.g. "the server is dying". But I would like to catch the error gracefully. I also tryed wrapping it in a try catch but without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
```

in your callback to tell Json.NET that you handled the exception. If you don't (maybe because you just want to log the error), the exception is thrown after your callback.

Comment: THank you so much.. This was exactly what I was looking for :)